# Excel Microsoft query using subquery and pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I am trying to run the following query in Excel and it gives me the message: 'Could not add the table"(......'

This works fine in SSMS. I am not an Excel pro. I think it is chocking on the subquery.
Any suggestions/syntax corrections to make it work in Excel?

Thanks

```
SELECT Pvt.GNumber, [4093], [4096], [4099], [4102] 
FROM
(
SELECT GNumber
, Convert(Integer, EndDate)+2 AS EndDate
, EndBal
FROM [Server].[Dbname].[dbo].[tblnumber] 
WHERE Number='00S' 
AND EndDate>=CONVERT(DateTime, '2012-01-31') 
AND EndDate<=CONVERT(DateTime, '2013-12-31')
)  Results

Pivot (
SUM(EndBalance)
FOR EndDate IN ([4093], [4096], [4099], [4102])
) AS Pvt
ORDER BY Pvt.GLNumber
```

Comment: When you say run in Excel, did you create a new connection to SQL Server and put this in the Command Text box in the Edit Query dialog?

Comment: Can you put it in a view, and point the query at that? Just a shot on the dark.

Comment: I know I have the option of putting it in a view or do a stored procedure if we want it to take parameters for Number.  But I was just wondering if I can work it around in Excel

Comment: Sorry, I'm not more help. I use this kind of functionality a lot, and have stuffed some pretty long SQL into that box, but it's all kind of magical to me. One other probably lame idea. Does it behave any better if you create the table as an MS Query connection (under From Other Sources)? Good luck!